# Circular Type References in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and am trying to understand how I can setup a circular reference between two types.  The reference need not be a full code reference, simply the interfaces, but with interfaces defined in separate files.  For example, let's say I have two interfaces: Parent and Child.  They are doubly-linked such that the parent has a collection of children and each child has a reference to the parent (as seen below).  How do I setup the imports or dependencies so that these can be defined in separate files?

```
interface Parent {
  children: Child[]
}

interface Child {
  parent: Parent
}
```

Comment: I would personally put them in the same file because they are inextricably linked and are both erased during compilation.

Comment: For ways to solve circular dependencies refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742533/3198983

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Two solutions below. I prefer the latter since it offers clean interfacing with Node JS modules, but unfortunately my IDE doesn't (yet) like it as much as I do...

**Use references**

Create a `definitions.d.ts` file that will only contain the references to your classes/interfaces

```
/// <reference path="Parent.ts" />
/// <reference path="Child.ts" />
```

In `Parent.ts` and `Child.ts`, point to a single reference, the `definitions.d.ts` file

```
/// <reference path="definitions.d.ts" />
```

**Use import...require**

pass the `--module commonjs` flag to `tsc` then `import` what you `require` and `export` what you want to expose

In Parent.ts

```
 import Child = require('Child')

 interface Parent { 
     children: Child[]
 }

 export = Parent
```

In Child.ts

```
 import Parent = require('Parent')
 
 interface Child {
     parent: Parent
 }

 export = Child
```

Please note, that you do not specify the extension '.ts' in `require`

Comment: Your edit of Sept 2016 (still) generates circular dependency messages with typescript: >=2.4.2 <2.7.0 and tslint: ^5.13.1

Comment: @BernoulliIT I removed the edit of 2016, which does not work anymore with more recent versions of typescript. The "solutions" above are still workarounds - a redesign is probably a better idea

Comment: @BrunoGrieder what kind of a "redesign". For strongly typed languages cycles are normal and expected behavior!

Comment: The VSCode plugin 'Unused exports' also doesn't see d.ts as a circular dependency :)

Comment: The `Use import...require` approach worked for me! TypeScript version `4.5.5` . For some reason the `Use references` approach also resulted in a circular dependency. And the accepted answer did not allow me to do `let c: Child = new Child()` (in my case, Parent and Child were classes, not interfaces).

Answer (score 53):

I also faced with the similar situation.

I could resolve by using `import type`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!

Comment: A very elegant and quick fix. I try to always keep up with TS but missed this TS3.8 feature. Doesn't help that the description downplays its usefulness: `This feature is something most users may never have to think about; however, if you’ve hit issues under isolatedModules, TypeScript’s transpileModule API, or Babel, this feature might be relevant.`

Answer (score 5):

I have about 10 ts files , in a Circular-Dependency-Hell .

The common methods can't help me any more ,  because the dependencies relation between 10 files is to complex.

At finally , I solved it. Using following 2 methods :

1. Install repo  ————  "circular-dependency-plugin": "5.0.2"

   This repo will helps me to find the place where circular occurs.
2. Using a designed internal.ts , to manage my import & export

   I tried the method of this article :

   [How to fix nasty circular dependency issues once and for all in JavaScript & TypeScript](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de)

   This amazing article tells me to create internal.ts .

   and using like `export * form 'file-A' ; export * from 'file-B'` to manage my circular dependencies.

   It works very well when I use dependencies related to my 10 files, like this `import classA from '../internal.ts'`.

————————————————————————————————————

If the above method has no effect on you, I found another general solution:

Use

`const File_Promise = import ('yourFilePath')"` to import other file or module .

when you need to use this one, use

`File_Promise.then (file => { file.xxx(file.yyy) })`
, just like using Promise syntax. 
`

**This will break the Circular-Dep Chain !**

**If i am you , I will continue this action until NO ERROR Reported by "circular-dependency-plugin".**

————————————————————————————————————

Hope to help YOU ！

Comment: I apply the same method but still im getting depencies warning like that


src/app/shared/entities/internal.ts > src/app/shared/entities/calender-event.entity.ts
 src/app/shared/entities/internal.ts > src/app/shared/entities/contact.entity.ts
6) src/app/shared/entities/internal.ts > src/app/shared/entities/email-template.entity.ts
7) src/app/shared/entities/internal.ts > src/app/shared/entities/goal.entity.ts
@Lancer.Yan

Comment: @Sanam I found a general solution. Use "const File_Promise = import ('yourFilePath')", when you need to use the function of the original File, use File_Promise.then (file => {}), just like using Promise syntax.