# How to create a circularly referenced type in TypeScript?

Tags: types, typescript, circular-reference

I have the following code:

```
type Document = number | string | Array<Document>;
```

TypeScript complains with the following error:

```
test.ts(7,6): error TS2456: Type alias 'Document' circularly references itself.
```

Clearly circular references are not allowed. However, I still need this kind of structure. What would be a workaround for this?

Comment: Apparently, circular type references are permitted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444436/circular-type-references-in-typescript

Comment: I got quite confused why the union type here was wrapped in square brackets. Probably that wasn't intended. See my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57132240/1804173).

Comment: @bluenote10 You're right, fixing it now.

Comment: Native support for recursive types is coming in TypeScript 3.7, see: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050

Comment: Cool! I'll update the question when it comes out.

Comment: Hmm still doesn't seem to work in TS 4.3.5

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The creator of TypeScript explains how to create recursive types [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540).

The workaround for the circular reference is to use `extends Array`. In your case this would lead to this solution:

```
type Document = number | string | DocumentArray;

interface DocumentArray extends Array<Document> { }
```

**Update (TypeScript 3.7)**

Starting with TypeScript 3.7, recursive type aliases will be permitted and  the workaround will no longer be needed. See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050

Comment: Great, so I am not the only crazy person doing so in my code! :)

Comment: I'm using TypeScript 4.3, and I still need this workaround for a more complex definition.

Comment: It is related to this issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41164

Answer (score 23):

We already have good answers, but I think we can get closer to what you wanted in the first place:

You may try something like this:

```
interface Document {
    [index: number]: number | string | Document;
}

// compiles
const doc1: Document = [1, "one", [2, "two", [3, "three"]]];

// fails with "Index signatures are incompatible" which probably is what you want
const doc2: Document = [1, "one", [2, "two", { "three": 3 }]];
```

Compared to NPE's answer, you don't need wrapper objects around strings and numbers.

If you want a single number or string to be a valid document (which is not what you asked, but what NPE's answer implies), you may try this:

```
type ScalarDocument = number | string;
interface DocumentArray {
    [index: number]: ScalarDocument | DocumentArray;
}
type Document = ScalarDocument | DocumentArray;

const doc1: Document = 1;
const doc2: Document = "one";
const doc3: Document = [ doc1, doc2 ];
```

**Update:**

Using an interface with index signature instead of an array has the disadvantage of losing type information. Typescript won't let you call array methods like find, map or forEach. Example:

```
type ScalarDocument = number | string;
interface DocumentArray {
    [index: number]: ScalarDocument | DocumentArray;
}
type Document = ScalarDocument | DocumentArray;

const doc1: Document = 1;
const doc2: Document = "one";
const doc3: Document = [ doc1, doc2 ];
const doc = Math.random() < 0.5 ? doc1 : (Math.random() < 0.5 ? doc2 : doc3);

if (typeof doc === "number") {
    doc - 1;
} else if (typeof doc === "string") {
    doc.toUpperCase();
} else {
    // fails with "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'DocumentArray'"
    doc.map(d => d);
}
```

This can be solved by changing the definition of DocumentArray:

```
interface DocumentArray extends Array<ScalarDocument | DocumentArray> {}
```

Comment: You may also fix certain indices to a specific type like so:

    interface DocumentArray {
        0: number;
        [index: number]: ScalarDocument | DocumentArray;
    }

Answer (score 17):

Here is one way to do it:

```
class Doc {
  val: number | string | Doc[];
}

let doc1: Doc = { val: 42 };
let doc2: Doc = { val: "the answer" };
let doc3: Doc = { val: [doc1, doc2] };
```

Types that reference themselves are known as "recursive types" and are discussed in [section 3.11.8](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.11.8) of the language spec. The following excerpt explains why your attempt does not compile:

> **Classes and interfaces** can reference themselves in their internal structure...

Your original example uses neither a class nor an interface; it uses a *type alias*.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! This answer definitely deserves to be higher.

Answer (score 11):

As of Typescript 4, circular types are fixed for a bunch of things, but not for Record (and it's by design).
Here's how you can do it if you come across this problem.

```js
// This will fire a TS2456 error: Type alias "Tree" circularly reference itself
type Tree = Record<string, Tree | string>;
```

```js
// No error
type Tree = {
    [key: string]: Tree | string;
};
```

ref: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050#issuecomment-543365074

Answer (score 1):

Building on what NPE said, types cannot recursively point to themselves,  you could unroll this type to whatever level of depth you considered sufficient, e.g.:

```
type Document = [number|string|[number|string|[number|string|[number|string]]]]
```

Not pretty, but removes the need for an interface or class with a property value.

Comment: Indeed, I thought of that, but unfortunately I need it to be of infinite depth. Thanks for the answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Circular = {
    infinity: Map<string, Circular>
}

type Store = Circular['infinity']

declare var map:Store;

const foo = map.get('sd') // Circular | undefined
```