# Modeling recursive types with generic type restriction

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to model a simple recursive relationship like the following? I want to restrict the types of values added to a generic container to primitives or other containers. Since interfaces can't extend from types, and types cannot reference themselves, it's not immediately clear whether this is possible:

```
  type Primitive = string | boolean | number | null;
  type Value = Primitive | MyMap<Value>;  // <-- error here


  interface MyMap<T extends Value> {
    get(k: string): T;
    set(k: string, v: T): void;
  }
```

Comment: Note that this question is similar to [an earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966444/how-to-create-a-circularly-referenced-type-in-typescript), although the specifics are possibly different enough to warrant keeping this as a separate question.  Not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Types *can* reference themselves (see the [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.11.8)), but there are definitely pitfalls.  For your specific case I would probably do something like:

```
type Primitive = string | boolean | number | null;

type Value = Primitive | MyMap; 

interface MyMap {
  get(k: string): Value;
  set(k: string, v: Value): void;
}
```

without the generic to confuse things.

---

#### Update 1

@Chris Colbert [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171290/modeling-recursive-types-with-generic-type-restriction#comment77312465_45171985):

> The generic is important though, because I want to be able to do things like this: `let m1: MyMap<string>; let m2: MyMap<MyMap<number>>;` and so on.

Okay, try:

```
type Primitive = string | boolean | number | null;

type Value = Primitive | {
  get(k: string): Value;
  set(k: string, v: Value): void;
}

interface MyMap<T extends Value> {
  get(k: string): T;
  set(k: string, v: T): void;
}

declare let m1: MyMap<string>; 
declare let m2: MyMap<MyMap<number>>;
```

Comment: The generic is important though, because I want to be able to do things like this:

```
let m1: MyMap<string>;
let m2: MyMap<MyMap<number>>;
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting that that works, but not my original example. Unfortunately, this is a minimal example, the real code has many more methods as well as other collection types, so it would be prohibitive to scale this pattern at that level.

Comment: Oh well, sorry.  Is there anything about my answer which needs changing before you'd accept it?