# Recursive Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let's suppose we try to create HTML build helper

```
build([
  'html', { lang: 'en' }, [
    ['head', [
      ['title', 'Hello, world!']
    ]
  ]
])
```

The type declaration for arguments of the `build` would be (actually it will be more complicated but let's consider just the simplest case)

```
type Node = [string, { [key: string]: string }, Node[]]
```

Unfortunately it didn't work, because TypeScript complains

```
TS2456: Type alias 'Node' circularly references itself.
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a circularly referenced type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966444/how-to-create-a-circularly-referenced-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 43):

Type aliases can't be circular, but interfaces can. This accomplishes what you want:

```
type MyTuple<T> = [string, { [key: string]: string }, T[]];
interface Node extends MyTuple<Node> { }
```

Comment: this is what I needed! :)

Answer (score 38):

This can now be done as of typescript 3.7: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#more-recursive-type-aliases

For example:

```
type ValueOrArray<T> = T | ValueOrArray<T>[];
type NestedStringArray = ValueOrArray<string>;

const nestedStringArray: NestedStringArray = [
  'hello',
  ['w', ['o', 'r', 'l'], 'd'],
];
```

Comment: is there a way to type it a way so it is flattened? Like ['hello', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']

Comment: @PEZO do you mean `string[]`? :) Typescript type definitions don't actually transform values, they just describe their type.

Comment: Haha, yes, I know. That's not how I meant. The following does not work: type X<T1> = T1 | X<T2> . I wanted to do something like that: type FullContextRecursive<Child> = GetSelfContext<Child> | FullContextRecursive<GetParentsOf<Child>> . I defined GetParentsOf<T> like a database earlier and I wanted to look up items from it. I know it is totally weird, but for my usecase it makes sense. Any ideas? :) Currently I made a workaround and explicitly passed a 16 deep expression instead of recursion.

Comment: Oh, interesting. That sounds like a good candidate for its own stack overflow question

Answer (score 12):

All of the answers here are dated as far as I can tell. In 2022 I just used the following to recursively scan a directory and save all the files and directories returned by the scan:

```
    type AbstractDirectory = {
      pathname: string;
      files: string[];
    };

    type AbstractFileTree = string | string[] | {
      [ key: string ]: AbstractFileTree;
      dirpath: string;
      filepaths: string[];
    };
```

Perhaps the most common need for recursive types, is the need to use a true JSON type. JSON is a format that can be as recursive as a programmer needs it to be.

Older versions of TypeScript *(pre `v3.7`)* typed JSON as shown here:

```
    type Json =  string | number | boolean | 
                 null | JsonObject | JsonArray;

    interface JsonObject {
        [property: string]: Json;
    }

    interface JsonArray extends Array<Json> {}
```

A good example that was [included in the ***`v3.7*** release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)  is demonstrated in the following snippet, which is a great solution to any recursive typing that you might be doing.

As of `v3.7` or newer, the following is valid TypeScript:

```
type Json =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | null
  | { [property: string]: Json }
  | Json[];
```

Both examples are recursive, but the later is a much cleaner, more readable, faster to write, easier to remember, and is just flat out a better abstract representation of what JSON is.

Answer (score 8):

Soon it will be much easier with Recursive type references https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050

Comment: This was merged and the code in the question now works fine.