# Typescript how to define array type with nested and predict

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

How to set the type for an array like

["string", [”string", ["other string"],["any"]], [”string", ["string”, ["something string"]]], ....]

That is, the depth can be any.
Number of arrays after index '0' is also.
The main condition, the type under the index '0' must be 'string'.

Answer (score 1):

From Ulad Kasach at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60722301/11745228,

This works:

```
type ValueOrArray<T> = T | ValueOrArray<T>[];
type NestedStringArray = ValueOrArray<string>;
```

Or, more directly for your answer:

```
type StringOrArray = string | StringOrArray[];
type NestedArray = StringOrArray;
```

Then just type your array with `NestedStringArray`

Comment: I found almost the same thing on your link.type NestedArray = string | [ string, ...NestedArray[] ]; its work.thanks