# Is there a way to make a recursive type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following type to get the common attributes between 2 objects:

```
type Common<T, U> = {
    [K in (keyof T & keyof U) as T[K] extends U[K] ? K : never]: T[K]
}
```

And I want to make it so that it can accept a multiple number of objects:

```
type Common3<A1, A2, A3> = Common<A1, Common<A2, A3>>
type Common4<A1, A2, A3, A4> = Common<A1, Common3<A2, A3, A4>
type Common5<A1, A2, A3, A4, A5> = Common<A1, Common4<A2, A3, A4, A5>
.
.
.
```

Is there any way I can do this? I thought I could use variadic types but it seems like it's only for use in functions.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/recursive-type-references

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842266

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966444

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050