# Why does TypeScript recursive type alias fail with generics

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-typings

I've got two type definitions describing almost the same thing:

```
 // compilation fails with `Type alias 'StringOrRecordOfStrings' circularly references itself.ts(2456)`
type StringOrRecordOfStrings = string | string[] | Record<string, StringOrRecordOfStrings>;

 // compiles without problems
type StringOrRecordOfStrings = string | string[] | { [property: string]: StringOrRecordOfStrings };
```

Is anyone able to explain why the first type definition doesn't compile?

- The recursive type aliases have been introduced in version 3.7 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#more-recursive-type-aliases
- This SO answer explains how to use recursive type aliases [Recursive Types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842266/recursive-types-in-typescript)
- for brevity I omitted the remaining key types from record, but it works even when we set the `[property: string | number | symbol]`.

Comment: Record and that type with an index signature are actually not equivalent and that may be why. If you look at the definition `Record` is a mapped type, which means it has to be expanded, but look! The value type is the alias! Then *that* has to be expanded as well, resulting in a circular reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `Record<string, StringOrRecordOfStrings>` is not allowed is that `Record` is a generic *type*, rather than a class or an interface.

There isn't a lot of clear documentation on this, but recursive type references for properties in objects, index signatures, and mapped types have been around for quite a while. The following works as early as TypeScript 3.3:

```
type Recursive = {p: Recursive} | {[p: string]: Recursive} | {[Key in 'a']: Recursive}
```

[TypeScript 3.3 playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=3.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDdoF4oG8wAuWBFDbAXygB8CBtYqVYZdAOwHMBdEuJNFgjU6+egGkIIKBygByAIZzepARWEAoDaEiryQgMIBJKHgAKyAPYBbdKggAefvuzGAfNvDRng7ABVTKHp2RGsAIwhkABooMMtLABsIBXYYn3U-bk9ddKEAQUDc7Dz6LK0daABlVg5OAHlkfktkABM6gDNqti5UQJZuzlpmGq5SoabWh37atIRmlqN2YEj2hXgIDw0OZeRV9dV5xZ296AgAD2X2Ft6JlqmRzhiu2obbjueetwJKIA)

This is why your second example type (with an index signature) checks.

TypeScript 3.7 extended the support for recursive references, as explained in this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050):

- Instantiations of generic class and interface types (for example `Array<Foo>`).
- Array types (for example `Foo[]`).
- Tuple types (for example `[string, Foo?]`).

So now, also these three examples are valid:

```
type RecursiveCI = Promise<RecursiveCI>
type RecursiveT = [number, boolean, RecursiveT]
type RecursiveA = RecursiveA[]
```

I assume the sample is just test code, but you can get it to type check by using a helper interface like this:

```
type StringOrRecordOfStrings = string | string[] | Record<string, RecordInterface>

interface RecordInterface extends Record<string, StringOrRecordOfStrings> {}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)

Comment: Thank you @Oblosys for the detailed explanation, I think that you can add the line:

`The reason why Record<string, StringOrRecordOfStrings> is not allowed is that Record is a generic type, rather than a class or an interface`

To the top of your comment, that looks like exactly the TL;DR answer to my question.

Comment: @UltraMaster Solid idea, done.