# How can I do a circularly referenced arbitrarily nested JSON type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to have an object like this:

```
{
  a1: {
    b1: {
      c1: {
        d1: 'foo',
        d2: {
          e1: 'bar'
        },
        d3: 'baz'
      },
      c2: 'hello'
    },
    b2: 'world',
    b3: {
      c1: {
        d1: 'another',
        d2: 'nested',
      }
    }
  },
  a2: 'thing'
}
```

Basically, the value associated with *any key* can be either a `string` or `Record<string, recurse>`... How can I accomplish this in TypeScript?

My attempt was:

```
type NestedRecordStringType = Record<string, RecordOrStringType>

type RecordOrStringType = string | Record<string, RecordOrStringType>
```

But it results in:

> Type alias 'RecordOrStringType' circularly references itself.ts(2456)

How do I accomplish this sort of thing? I would then create a map:

```
const map: MyType = {
  a1: {
    b1: {
      c1: {
        d1: 'foo',
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It must be something obvious I am missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive Types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842266/recursive-types-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it without using `Record`

```js
type MyType = string | {
    [key: string]: MyType
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXDAsgTwCqYA4CmMAvDAN4CwAUDLTAgIxqU11sBGT51bvdwXFn2F04XAOQAzECHEAaHiOFwATM0VKlBCewQAncRs10AvgtbHRAZjTjdAL0MWlZoyOBqY4gBYEANn6ybqbmIuye4gDuIHp+cPLBtOw23M7ugolKYrYIYCBQvgahlqIRYATQBPHFmiaZdc6uzggRBQCWYADmTg3UUPhEWLiEJDDQeh2dMAA+qWwA2gDWBJho45MAumhDA9QNQA)