# Typing object with arbitrary depth

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible in Typescript to define a type with an arbitrary number of nested objects?

To simplify the question, let's only consider typing a basic JSON object that only has string entries. So, a property of this JSON object would either be another basic JSON object, or a string.

This would be an example:

```
const obj = {
    propA: 'a string';
    propB: {
        propA: 'a string';
        propB: {
            propA: 'a string';
        }
    };
}
```

So this example has a "depth" of 2 (or 3, depending on how you count).

Is it possible to type this object, but more generally any object with arbitrary depth? I couldn't come up with a solution, particularly recursive types are disallowed in Typescript, i.e.

```
type A = A & string | string; // does not compile
```

I could not define a type using helper types either, for the same reason. At some point, a type had to be self-referential, at least in my experience.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966444/how-to-create-a-circularly-referenced-type-in-typescript ?

Comment: Wow, from the creator himself! I believe this answers my question. If it does, I'll report back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a circularly referenced type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966444/how-to-create-a-circularly-referenced-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Works :) thanks for the link!