# Typescript Generics for nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

Hello i am trying to add correct type to object with nested values.

Here is code in sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/0tftsf

```
interface Product {
  name: string,
  id: number
  productList?:ProductItem[]
}

interface ProductItem { 
  color: string, 
  size: number 
 }


type IValidation<T> = {
  field: keyof T
  nestedValidations?: IValidation<
    Pick<
      T,
      {
        [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends object ? K : never
      }[keyof T]
      >
    >[] // THIS IS IMPORTANT FOR QUESTION!
  validators?: (any | any | any)[]
}

export async function validateIt<T>(payload: T, validations: IValidation<T>[]): Promise<
  Partial<{
    [key in keyof T]: string[]
  }>
  > { 
    return Promise.resolve(payload);
  }

const product: Product = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'playstation',
  productList: [{
    color: 'red',
    size: 32
    }
  ]
}

const test = validateIt<Product>(product, [
  {
    field: "productList",
    validators: [],
    nestedValidations: [
      {
        field: 'color',
        validators: []
      }
    ]
  }
])
```

So getting type error and overall i am trying to find correct type for **nestedValidations** property, which should match **interface Product**

[image: ERROR]

Comment: updated with an idea

Answer (score 2):

### Typescript v3.7 and later

You can achieve this with `in` keyword in combination with `keyof`.
Basically you're going to "generate" all possible types for each key and typescript will find matching one

```js
type IValidation<T> = T extends Array<infer R> ? IValidation<R> : T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        field: K
        nestedValidations?: IValidation<T[K]>[]
        validators?: (any | any | any)[]
    }
}[keyof T] : never
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCzIDeAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYA0pywWdIOlAI2icADplz4AMsEY102PGACSkSgG0AusQC%20xYqEixEKeROWqiyTggwAbDFDqNmIdlbL1gAL1rl%20QqHddYjAATxEUADU4W244MGAMEAAeABUAPmQAXmRU5AgAD0gQLHpkAEEoKDhQ5NAYaGQAJUyAfmRo2Kx4xJSW5Do8wuLS5AwBACsIfGR2kjIyNQBpLhBkAGsIUIwYXI06eYWjmGAIWx5kJc4jshAIRggsTriEpPpWumfu15TU5Y10pprjcAG4xF4Od50AAUcBAoWQAB9kHCEcjUQBKIFHXTaNSbba7VIaAbkCAg4TEQoiBwEOD0UIgBDIGA4Jk-ZBgrrxCAqNLpaEiGr2OAXVJsTng769eifKU9JL8zQYujySgyCDJTioOBQBIxZKHRYE1YbLY7PZOJisbHIbTpTiZQjuBZQCBgHBQNZqjUAOjd9DsFMFwowooxAG5OMEbCBGMgxAp8KrxIpskRONw6ABGDi3Ki%20ADkIlsNUYCpAhbzCdTUhkYDoaiNyBs9kcyELbqwVeBnh8dAAzAAmYG6MhaGNvAiQeM5LkvXlgZKmRQCxNmCVqTjNsgnM4XYu1sDSRg9m5kh5PeU-WXILfno47h%20707nOiF1sOQvA8-aavPp9nz3N8O1Aedux-G4xxuLQyF0DQMSAA)

---

###### This doesn't work in older typescript versions, because they don't allow recursive types. [Link to info.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#more-recursive-type-aliases)

Comment: Perfect sir own you a beer please vote up! Tnx once again!

Comment: I think this is not right since gettng Type alias 'IValidation' circularly references itself error

Comment: Thanks, I've added info that this only works with TS versions that support recursive types (3.7+)

Comment: tnx, but is there some workaround for older types?

Comment: Maybe something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966444/how-to-create-a-circularly-referenced-type-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't see the big picture but I think you want to achieve this:

```
interface Product {
  name: string,
  id: number
}

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]; // not needed

type IValidation<T> = {
  field: keyof T
  nestedValidations?: IValidation<T>[] // THIS IS IMPORTANT FOR QUESTION!
  validators?: (any | any | any)[]
}

export async function validateIt<T>(payload: T, validations: IValidation<T>[]): Promise<
  Partial<{
    [key in keyof T]: string[]
  }>
  > { 
    return Promise.resolve(payload);
  }

const product: Product = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'playstation'
}

const test = validateIt<Product>(product, [
  {
    field: "id",
    validators: [],
    nestedValidations: [
      {
        field: "name",
        validators: []
      }
    ]
  }
])
```

Play around here: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCzIDeAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYA0pywWdIOlAI2jEAvsWJgAngAcUANTgAbHBADyMADwAVAHzIAvMi0BtANYRJGGEYC6AbmQB6R%20QwEQECFi-ips5ACSCorccGDAGCDaeoYkZDDAEIo8yOaW1lqcHoxewaHhkfQA-HRBSvkRUbrGNk4uWgASAQDKga0BALKoqgBKWgCCAHJayABivcgAigCqAKLNWgGqgwCEnABu5VhhGFDFdAAUcCCSyAA%20yMenF1cAlDWi4hAAHtK7BHD0kiAIyDA4PwKIGQmxC20gATA0QO0jgkkUGDgKS0bBBWzClXopTy4Mq0Rqtzo6AwlGA9AgGk4qDgUHCSg0cTIyDMFi4wLSVlsdEYzBALAeZBEOk4ekIyE4ZCgEDAOCgwOJpPJADopfQMIp1hAYXCEUjbnZOGJiAhCgRpJhcPgiRa8ARYpxuHQAIwcMgUah0ADk0kUcMYGMinsextNyEgjAMaLBYQgkI0xMtYB0MJt%20FRxk4jPiiWSdAARNw866maD8rsscybMW3RAclgcQGQBWM0ymVnW38cyk8%206IEWJR3S%20Dy3QBR2xK2bIbiDZbkA)

Please note that I had to simplify your data structure since I don't know how 'IRequiredValidator' is defined.

So basically we switch from

```
nestedValidations?: IValidation<ValueOf<T>>[]
```

to

```
nestedValidations?: IValidation<T>[]
```

because you want to extract the keys of T and not the keys of ( keys of T) Since that would resolve to all the properties of the type of a value assigned to a property of T.

Comment: No IValidation<T>[] will use just a storeProductImageList key, i need here this part StoreProductImage from

export type PostStoreProductPayload = {
  storeProductImageList?: StoreProductImage[]
}

Comment: updated with an idea it is close but no cigar

Comment: here it is code in sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/0tftsf

Comment: I was playing around with your example and came up with `type IValidation<T, P extends keyof T> = { field: P, validators?: ..., nestedValidations?: IValidation<T[P], keyof T[P]>[]; }` However, there's an issue with trying to define types and validation for types like this: what is a key of a `ProductItem[]`? `0`, `1`, `2`, ... You should try reapproaching the design with the [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.

Comment: do you have some examples?