# How does circular referencing work in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tsc

When I studied components of react such as ReactFragment, ReactNode, JSX.Element, and so forth, I encountered something incomprehensible.

in react source code, there are codes that I could not understand.

```
type ReactFragment = Iterable<ReactNode>;
type ReactNode = ReactElement | string | number | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

In this code, the type `ReactFragment` is refenced by `ReactNode`, and vice versa.
I thought it was an error due to circular references, but it runs very well.

So, I wrote two pieces of code, one that works and one that doesn't.

Normal(It runs well.)

```
type A = Iterable<B>;
type B = A | number;
```

Wrong(Syntax Error)

```
type A = B | string;
type B = A | string;
```

What is the difference between the two codes? except for the use of Iterable in type A.

I tried to understand `tsc` (the TypeScript compiler) and here's what I learned:

- The scanner tokenizes every token such as whitespace, identifiers, etc.
- The parser makes an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) using tokens generated by the scanner.
- The checker checks the AST tree to generate JavaScript code.

If I have provided any incorrect information regarding `tsc`, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: A thing to investigate: perhaps an iterable does not depend quite so much on the type underneath when interpreted down to assembly - ultimately an iterable needs to know very different things that lean only superficially  - like size - on the underlying type. This is not an answer / comment with a lot of confidence from me, but it is where I would begin my investigation on the subject.

Comment: Actually when I did test for this, I used B[] rather than Iterator<B>. It runs well. By the way, there is error 'Type alias 'A' circularly references itself.: 2456' when I wrote wrong syntax like above. For finding error, I checked getDeclaredTypeOfTypeAlias funciton in checker.ts in typescript source file. It throws error number 2456.

Answer (score 1):

Not all circular references are allowed in TypeScript, but some recursive references are supported. [There used to be even more restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966444/how-to-create-a-circularly-referenced-type-in-typescript) but [TS3.7 extended the support for constructing recursive types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050).

Specifically, circular references are allowed in aliased types if:

- you're referencing it in a generic class or interface type (e.g. `Iterator<B>`)
- you're referencing it in an Array type (e.g. `B[]`)
- or you're declaring a Tuple type (e.g. `[A, B]`)

The circular references are only really a problem if it introduces an infinite loop. A tree type typically contains recursive references without introducing circularity:

```js
type TreeNode<T> = { value: T, children?: Children<T> }
type Children<T> = TreeNode<T>[]
```

Of course, you can create a recursive type alias that can never be satisfied:

```js
type X = [X,X]
```

This isn't a syntax error, and TypeScript won't stop you from doing it, but you'll never actually have a value of that type.