# Best way to resolve circular dependencies in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, circular-dependency

I'm working on a simple API for a website in TypeScript, the code works well but I've a circular dependency that I need to fix.

A (very) minimal example of the project can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-perlman-lpq6gh

Which is the best way to fix circular dependency of api/index.ts in this example?

I've tried to use an inherit class, but I don't know the best way to call a class child from another child.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular Type References in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444436/circular-type-references-in-typescript)

Comment: No really. I thought about using a third file but I don't like that solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly run the following cli command to get a list of circular dependencies, then you will notice what to do:
Further instruction for madge [here](https://github.com/pahen/madge)

```
npx madge --circular --extensions ts ./
```

Comment: Well, according to madge, I don't have circular dependencies. But clearly in the codesandbox I am importing two files that import into each other.

Comment: then you have found the cyclic

Comment: So cyclic dependencies and circular dependencies are not the same?

Comment: isnt a synonym? It isThanks!

Comment: Thank you too. But I'm confused rn, they are synonym, but they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

After several tries with Madge I checked with lint and the result was much better.

Madge was able to find:

```
✖ Found 2 circular dependencies!

1) context.ts > issuer-context-middleware.ts
2) context.ts > issuer-context-middleware.ts > slauth-middleware.ts
```

lint implementing import/no-cycle:

```
/src/anon-request-middleware.ts
  3:1  error  Dependency cycle via .:18  import/no-cycle

/src/claims-middleware.ts
  5:1  error  Dependency cycle via .:18  import/no-cycle

/src/context.ts
  18:1  error  Dependency cycle detected  import/no-cycle
  23:1  error  Dependency cycle detected  import/no-cycle

/src/index.ts
  10:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./context:3  import/no-cycle
  13:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./context:5  import/no-cycle
  16:1  error  Dependency cycle detected         import/no-cycle
  18:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./context:3  import/no-cycle
  19:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./context:3  import/no-cycle
  20:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./context:6  import/no-cycle
  44:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./context:5  import/no-cycle
  50:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./context:6  import/no-cycle
  51:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./context:3  import/no-cycle

/src/internal-request-middleware.ts
  3:1  error  Dependency cycle via .:18  import/no-cycle

/src/issuer-context-middleware.ts
  3:1  error  Dependency cycle detected         import/no-cycle
  4:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./context:6  import/no-cycle

/src/slauth-middleware.ts
  6:1  error  Dependency cycle via .:18  import/no-cycle
```

I do recommend https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-cycle.md